# Extend autogenerated swagger document to contain specific endpoints?

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-core, swagger, swagger-codegen

I currently have a set of endpoints which which follows the structure

```
/api/{book}/read
/api/{book}/change
```

where it would be nice to have swagger autogenerate which books could be read and changed?

but the swagger autogenerated open api doc, contains the general definition.

the information of which books can be read and changed is stored in the database, is somehow possible to link the documentation to what is actually in the database?

Comment: interested in this aswell